# Search with fixed values (Y:Yes;N:No) in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, jqgrid

I would like to know how to search in jqGrid when the column value is fixed (select).

Ex : Column Name is Status and values is O:Open;C:Closed;P:Partial Open
At the back end it stores O/C/P.

In my jqGrid I used select for this column and stored these value.

Now when I search in jqGrid for this column. 
Say : Status='Open' it takes Status='Open' instead of Status='O'.

I want to know how to deal with such issues as the user will type text part of select and at the back end it is stored  as value.

```js
 $("#ListOfActivity").jqGrid({
         url: ServiceUrl,
         datatype: 'json',
         mtype: 'POST',
         beforeRequest: function () {
             //alert('beforeRequest');
         },
         loadError: function (xhr, status, error) {
             $(this).HideBusy();
             //   alert(status);
             //     alert(error);
             alert(xhr.responseText);
         },
         gridComplete: function () {
         },

         loadComplete: function (data) {
             $(this).HideBusy();
         },
         ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
         serializeGridData: function (postData) {
             if (postData.searchField === undefined) postData.searchField = null;
             if (postData.searchString === undefined) postData.searchString = null;
             if (postData.searchOper === undefined) postData.searchOper = null;
             if (postData.filters === undefined) postData.filters = null;
             return JSON.stringify(postData);
         },
         ondblClickRow: function (rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {

             EditActivity(event, rowid, iRow, iCol, e, evt);

         },
         jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, root: "d.rows", page: "d.page", total: "d.total", records: "d.records" },
         colNames: ['Number', 'Type', 'Customer Code', 'CardType', 'Customer Name', 'Closed', 'Start Date', 'End Date', 'Remark', 'Status'],
         colModel: [
       { name: 'Number', key: true, index: 'Number asc', sortable: false, align: "center", width: 40, search: false },
       { name: 'ActionDesc', index: 'ActionDesc', sortable: false, align: "left", width: 70, search: false },
       { name: 'CardCode', index: 'CardCode', sortable: false, align: "left", width: 80, search: true },

       { name: 'CardType', index: 'CardType', sortable: false, align: "left", width: 50, search: false },
       { name: 'CardName', index: 'CardName', sortable: false, align: "left", width: 150, search: true },
       { name: 'Closed', index: 'Closed', sortable: false, align: "left", width: 100, search: true, editable: true,
           edittype: 'select',
           formatter: 'select',
           editoptions: { value: 'Y:Yes;N:No' },
           formatter: function (cellValue, opts, rawdata, action) {
               //debugger;
               if (cellValue == 'Y')
                   return 'Yes';
               else
                   return 'No';
           }
       },
       { name: 'ActStartDate', index: 'ActStartDate', sortable: false, align: "left", width: 100, search: false, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'yyyyMMdd', newformat: 'd-M-y'} },
       { name: 'ActEndDate', index: 'ActEndDate', sortable: false, align: "left", width: 100, search: false, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'yyyyMMdd', newformat: 'd-M-y'} },
       { name: 'Details', index: 'Details', sortable: false, align: "left", width: 130, search: true },
       { name: 'Status', index: 'Status', sortable: false, align: "left", width: 80, search: true }
      ],
         rowNum: 13,
         pager: "#ListOfActivityMap",
         viewrecords: true,
         gridview: true,
         rownumbers: true,
         height: 300,
         width: 1300,
         caption: 'List of Activities',
         scrollOffset: 0
     }).jqGrid('navGrid', '#ListOfActivityMap', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, searchOnEnter: true, search: true }, {}, {}, {}, { multipleSearch: true });
```

Comment: Can you add jqgrid code.....

Comment: Any comment on this issue???